# How to inherit autocomplete for arguments when using ellipsis (...)

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have a function `foo` with some documentation, using `roxygen2`.

```r
#' @param a description a
#' @param b description b
foo <- function(a, b, c){
        cat(a, b, c)
    }
```

I have written a wrapper, `foo_wrapper`, whose help file inherit all parameters, but `a`, from `foo`. They show as expected in the help file.

```r
#' @inheritDotParams foo -a
foo_wrapper <- function(a, ...){
    foo(a = "a", ...)
}
```

The autocomplete only show the arguments `a` and `...` from `foo_wrapper`. How can I get it to suggest the parameters from `foo` instead, i.e. the same parameters that are in the help file from `foo_wrapper`?
Found this [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13414) which seem related, but not the same problem.

Comment: It's because  there's no way for a parser to autocomplete arbitrary argument names.  Remember that `...` is normally used to pass args to a func called inside the main function, so the main (ie.. in your case the wrapper) func has no idea what those argument names are.

Comment: but the parameters that are inherited from foo are not arbitrary. What could be a reson to not to get autocomplete on the parameters that are in the documentation of foo_wrapper, which are inherited from foo?

Comment: @wasserlasken your question doesn't make any sense.  foo_wrapper has only one defined variable "a"  . There is no internal 'inheritance' going on.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft sorry, I'm being a bit unclear. When referring to inheritance, its with regard to documentation and autocomplete not the actual parameters of foo. My question is basically:  if the documentation can inherit, why can't the autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do that is to copy the parameter names, i.e. define `foo_wrapper` as

```
foo_wrapper <- function(a, b, c){
  foo(a = "a", b = b, c = c)
}
```

The autocomplete is usually based on the function definition, and `@inheritDotParams` has no effect on the function definition, it only affects the Rd documentation file that is produced.

If you are really determined to do it, you could use the methods described in `?rcompgen`.  For example, running

```
utils:::.addFunctionInfo(foo_wrapper = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

will cause the base R GUIs to offer all three arguments as completions.  It appears that the RStudio completion code doesn't pay any attention to this.  I don't know if there's a way to do it if you're using RStudio.

Comment: Since foo might change parameters over a development phase and there might be multiple foo_wrappers it defeats the purpose to hardcode the call with explicit parameters, a bit.